# Starting a new thread using django and apache

Tags: django, multithreading, apache

I am writing a web application using django and part of it requires me to download images given by google image search and store it in a directory onto the server. Here is the code I have written:

`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        image = request.FILES['image_file']
        query = json.loads(request.POST['metadata'])
        owner = User.objects.filter(username="jane")[0]
        imageSearch = utils.GoogleImageSearch(query=query['query'], user=owner)
        instance = ModelInstance(user=owner, raw_image=image, metadata=str(query))
        instance.save()
        someThread = utils.SomeThread(InstanceModel=instance, googleImageSearch=imageSearch)
        someThread.start() #This line does not start a new thread on apache
        someThread.join()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`

Here is my utils.py

`class GoogleImageSearch(object):
    query = ""
    directoryToSave = ""
    numberOfImages = ""
    user = ""`

    `def initializeDirectoryStructure(self):
        pathToStoreImages = self.directoryToSave
        if os.path.exists(pathToStoreImages):
            shutil.rmtree(pathToStoreImages)
        os.makedirs(pathToStoreImages)`

```
def __init__(self, query, user):
    self.query = query
    self.numberOfImages = constants.NUMBER_OF_SEARCH_RESULTS
    self.user = user
    self.directoryToSave = os.path.join(constants.IMAGE_CONTAINER_ROOT, user.username)
    self.initializeDirectoryStructure()

    def ImageSearch(self):
    exitCode, numberOfImages = imagesearch.searchAndSave(self.query, os.path.join(constants.IMAGE_CONTAINER_ROOT, self.user.username) , constant$
```

class SomeThread(Thread):
    def **init**(self, mosaicModel, googleImageSearch):
        Thread.**init**(self)
        self.mosaicModel = mosaicModel
        self.googleImageSearch = googleImageSearch
    def run(self):
        self.googleImageSearch.ImageSearch()

When I run this code with the django development server, it runs fine.
But when I run this on Apache, the thread never starts.

I am guessing that apache does not allow new threads to be created from the django application.
I wanted to know if there any way(may be some apache configuration file changes) to start the thread.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution? (I have a similiar problem)

Comment: It is not a good practice to spawn new threads. So, I started using Celery instead, to make my application do certain tasks asynchronously.